# How to store numeric type in BigQuery using node js client for streaming insert?

Tags: google-bigquery

Given that numeric type in BigQuery supports limits way beyond the number type of Javascript, how do I store a numeric type using the node js client `Table.insert(rows, options, callback)` method? For handling big numbers using string type, I was considering using https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js. If I send a string value (containing a valid number beyond javascript's number limit) for a numeric field in my BigQuery table, will it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to treat the numbers that are too big for JavaScript as strings.

For example, JS doesn't know how to handle `-99999999999999999999999999999.999999999`:

[image]

Meanwhile this code works in NodeJS to insert that huge number into BigQuery:

```
BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
bigquery = BigQuery({projectId: 'my-project'});
dataset = bigquery.dataset('tt');
table = dataset.table('testfun_numeric');

rows = [{
  name:"whatever",
  numi: "-99999999999999999999999999999.999999999"
}];
table.insert(rows);
```

And in BigQuery:

```
SELECT name, numi 
  , numi=numi+1000 better_comparison
FROM `fh-bigquery.tt.testfun_numeric`
```

[image]

I previously created the table in BigQuery with

```
CREATE TABLE `tt.testfun_numeric`
AS
SELECT '' name, CAST(0 AS NUMERIC) numi 
LIMIT 0
```

FWIW, I also tried `BigInt(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)` in NodeJS, but the library wouldn't send it correctly to BigQuery - unless I converted it into a string first.