# What is the difference between NUMERIC and FLOAT in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I read the docs:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data

I know that `FLOAT` is 8 bytes while `NUMERIC` is 16 bytes
Is that the only difference? 
The docs says that `NUMERIC` can range `-99999999999999999999999999999.999999999` to `99999999999999999999999999999.999999999` but it doesn't specify the range for `FLOAT`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I like the current answers. I want to add this as a proof of why `NUMERIC` is necessary:

```
SELECT 
  4.35 * 100 a_float
  , CAST(4.35 AS NUMERIC) * 100 a_numeric
```

[image]

This is not a bug - this is exactly how the [IEEE defines floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) should be handled. Meanwhile `NUMERIC` exhibits behavior closer to what humans expect.

For another proof of `NUMERIC` usefulness, this answer shows how `NUMERIC` can handle [numbers too big for JavaScript to normally handle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54341147/132438).

Before you blame BigQuery for this problem, you can check that most other programming languages will do the same. Python, for example:

[image]

Comment: The question is if I'm working only with 3 digits after dot. float is good enough?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many digits after dot. See the example above - 4.35 has only 2, but some mathematical operations can screw its representation. Still, float is good enough for most uses, even tho sometimes it can surprise you.

Comment: 16 bytes is good enough for a precision of 1/1000, and i think up to 10^-10. 64 bit floats usually have 53 manissa bits and 11 exponent bits. so worst case scenario, a number between 2^10 to 2^11 can be accurately represented up to a multiple of 2^(11-53) = 2^-42. and that's about 10^-10. someone please correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 10):

There are quite a few differences:

- Range: `FLOAT` can be get as big as ±2^1023 (although it can't represent every integer in this range)
- Precision near zero: near zero, `FLOAT` can be as precise as 2^-1022.
- NaN/Inf: `FLOAT` has "not a number" and positive and negative "infinite" values, while `NUMERIC` does not.
- Storage size: each `NUMERIC` requires 16 bytes storage, but `FLOAT` only requires 8 bytes.
- Unpredictable nature: As Ajay hints at, the big drawback to `FLOAT` is that the numbers that it can precisely represent don't really align that  closely with the numbers we are typically interested in. As a result, floating point should be used for physical quantities where some error is acceptable. If you require predictable, exact human-predictable results, like in financial calculations, use `NUMERIC`

Answer (score 8):

The main difference is Floats / Doubles are binary floating point types and a Numeric will store the value as a floating decimal point type. So Numeric have much higher precision and are usually used within monetary (financial) applications that require a high degree of accuracy. But in performance wise Numeric are slower than double and float types.Numeric can 100% accurately represent any number within the precision of the decimal format, whereas Float and Double, cannot accurately represent all numbers, even numbers that are within their respective formats precision.