# Pandas dataframe with float64 incorrectly exported by to_json() function

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, decimal-point

This issue is about exporting the dataframe with float64 datatype, using the `to_json()` function from Pandas. The source code is attached below.

```
import pandas

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = {'col1': [11111111.84, 123456.55], 'col2': [3, 4]}
    df = pandas.DataFrame(data=d)

    print(df)
    print(df.dtypes)

    output_file_path = '/test.csv'
    df.to_csv(output_file_path, index=False, encoding='UTF-8')
    output_file_path = '/test.json'
    df.to_json(output_file_path, orient="records", lines=True)
```

The output from `print()` function is correct before exporting the dataframe into JSON or CSV file. The output is shown below.

```
          col1  col2
0  11111111.84     3
1    123456.55     4
col1    float64
col2      int64
dtype: object
```

The exported data in CSV format (test.csv) is correct as it should be.

[image]

The exported data in JSON format (test.json) has the **incorrect** decimal points as shown below in col1 row1 ***(11111111.8399999999)***. This issue only occurs for some values because col1 row2 is correct *(123456.55)*.

[image]

I found that there is a workaround to fix this issue by specifying another argument `double_precision` for `to_json()` function. The result becomes correct! (already tested.)

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

However, by specifying `double_precision` argument, it might limit the number of decimal points to all columns. It is not a good approach when each data column requires different numbers of decimal points.

Also, found the topic below but not sure if it is related to this issue of mine.

Link: [What is the difference between NUMERIC and FLOAT in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789526/what-is-the-difference-between-numeric-and-float-in-bigquery)

I am trying to understand the root cause of this issue and look for the solution. This is quite weird that the issue only happens for `to_json()` function, but `to_csv()` function works.

Anyone please help!

Comment: It's odd that pandas to_csv() and to_json() treat your number differently.
See here for a discussion on pandas float formatting for to_csv() that likely also pertains to to_json() https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16452

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas `to_json` might be doing something weird with the precision there. As you've explained, the canonical solution is to specify `double_precision` with your desired precision, but this doesn't allow you to selectively round *specific* columns to a desired precision.

Another option is to cut out the middleman `df.to_json` here and instead use python's builtin [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```
import json

# convert to string
json.dumps(df.to_dict()) 
# '{"col1": {"0": 11111111.84, "1": 123456.55}, "col2": {"0": 3, "1": 4}}'  

# save as a file
json.dump(df.to_dict(), f)  # f is an open fileobj
```

As you can see, this doesn't muck around with the precision. [Standard floating point caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) still apply.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing another workaround. It is helpful for handling this kind of issue. I will keep researching the issue further.