# Weird decimal values obtained through SQL type casting

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a very peculiar situation happening while doing a simple division using GoogleSQL.

For example, variables involved:

```
   Fruit_name -- String
   price_purchased -- String
   used_discount -- double
```

Example values:

| fruit_name | price_purchased | used_discount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 5 | 0.8 |
| pear | 6 | 0.76 |

A simple division through SQL to find out original price:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  fruit_name,
  CAST(price_purchased AS double),
  used_discount,
  CAST(price_purchased AS double) / (1 - used_discount) as original_price
FROM
  fruit_table
```

I'm weirdly getting such a result:

| fruit_name | price_purchased | used_discount | original_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 5 | 0.8 | 25.000000000000007 |
| pear | 6 | 0.76 | 25 |

The original price for the apple should also give me a value of 25 exactly, just like how the pear's value was also at 25.

How is it that the value of the apple's original price could have that weird minuscule amount? Is this due to some type casting issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The division result is floating point value, you need to it to `NUMERIC` type:

```
SELECT
  CAST(5 AS FLOAT64) / (1 - 0.8) AS float_original_price,
  CAST(CAST(5 AS FLOAT64) / (1 - 0.8) AS NUMERIC) AS numeric_original_price
```

| float_original_price | numeric_original_price |
| --- | --- |
| 25.000000000000007 | 25 |

You can refer to the docs for [Bigquery Numeric Types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#numeric_types). Also, check this post : [What is the difference between NUMERIC and FLOAT in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789526/what-is-the-difference-between-numeric-and-float-in-bigquery)

Comment: Thanks @bloackbishop for the tip!
But I'm still a little confused, why the DOUBLE data type get translated to FLOAT in this case? In typical mysql, casting it as double usually won't end up with such results. 

Why is it that type casting price_purchased as a NUMERIC right from the start then won't work as well?

Comment: @lyk which database are you using? Bigquery has no data type Double but Float

Comment: I'm using GoogleSQL on Dremel Engine, maybe I got a little bit confused back there but I will try to read up into this, thank you so much!