# Updating data and casting to new datatype

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, casting, sql-update

I'm working on Google BigQuery to analyze sample movie data.

The movie ratings are stored with spaces between the number and decimal point, so when I uplaoded the CSV file, Google BigQuery stored them as `STRING`. My goal is to first remove the empty spaces and then change the data type to `FLOAT`.

I removed the empty spaces using the following query:

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(Movie_Rating, ' ', '') AS Movie_Rating_Updated
FROM   Movies.Movies_Showtime
```

This is just a snippet of the whole data:

| Movie_Name | Movie_Rating | Movie_Rating_Updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fight Club | 8 . 8 | 8.8 |
| Schindler's List | 8 . 9 | 8.9 |

However, I was unsure about how to change the data type afterward, modifying the orginal table.

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a `SELECT` statement, you may want to use an `UPDATE` here, and use `PARSE_NUMERIC` to parse your string to numeric and update your column datatype:

```
UPDATE Movies.Movies_Showtime
SET Movie_Rating = PARSE_NUMERIC(REPLACE(Movie_Rating, ' ', ''))
```

Some [hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789526/what-is-the-difference-between-numeric-and-float-in-bigquery) on why it's better to store data with `NUMERIC` instead of `FLOAT` datatype.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But, can I use the UPDATE statement without a WHERE clause?

Comment: Yes, the only difference when you don't use a `WHERE` clause is that all records will get updated.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach using `SAFE_CAST` instead of `UPDATE`. `SAFE_CAST` will return `null` if value cannot be casted.

```
WITH
  Movies_Showtime AS (
  SELECT
    "Fight Club" AS Movie_Name,
    '8 .8' AS Movie_Rating
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    "Schindler's List",
    '8  .9'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    "Some other movie with invalid rating",
    'abc'
)
    
SELECT
  *,
  SAFE_CAST(REPLACE(Movie_Rating, ' ', '') AS NUMERIC) AS Movie_Rating_Updated
FROM
  Movies_Showtime
```